# Как правильно сделать запрос в базу MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Вопрос следующий, есть некоторое кол-во скриптов, они пишут результаты своей работы в базу. Этот запрос выбирает просто 10 последних записей отсортированных по дате, после чего PHP на базе полученного ответа строит таблицу с последними записями, но там все скрипты вперемешку.

```
SELECT TOP 10 [name]
             ,[description]
             ,[date]
             ,[status]                             
FROM [script_monitoring].[dbo].[status] order by DATE desc
```

Как улучшить этот запрос, чтобы ответ был такого же вида, только для каждого скрипта индивидуально? Можно было бы организовать цикл с запросами по каждому имени скрипта отдельно, но вместо 1 запроса использовать 10 мне кажется глупо. Могут ли в этом вопросе помочь временные таблицы? Важно чтобы это был целостный запрос.

Comment: Ответ на Ваш вопрос в том виде в котором вы его изначально задали может быть только один! "Напишите запрос для каждой таблицы чтобы брал последние 10 записей отсортированных по дате". Хотите конкретики - дайте и нам конкретики, что за таблицы что за скрипты и что не получается?

Comment: Первые 10 в mssql пишется так `select top 10` сортировать `order by поле`. Более иcчерпывающую информацию по даному вопросу обозначить не возможно.

Comment: _чтобы ответ был такого же вида, только для каждого скрипта индивидуально?_ Уточните. Нужно для каждого скрипта 10 последних записей? Для каждого - последнюю запись? Для 10 последних скриптов по последней записи? что-то ещё? Но в любом случае смотрите в сторону `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [script_id] ORDER BY [date] DESC)`.

Comment: @Akina Нужно для каждого скрипта 10 последних записей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Нужно для каждого скрипта 10 последних записей.

```
SELECT t1.[name]
     , t1.[description]
     , t1.[date]
     , t1.[status]
FROM (
      SELECT t0.[name]
           , t0.[description]
           , t0.[date]
           , t0.[status]
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t0.[name] ORDER BY t0.[date] DESC) rownum
      FROM table t0
      ) t1
WHERE rownum <= 10
```

Comment: скажите а что значит t1 и t0?

Comment: Алиасы это. Псевдонимы по-нашему ежели.

Comment: Это переменные что-ли?

Answer (score -3):

В реляционных БД нет понятия последние N записей. Сортировка так же не обязательна. Можно сделать что то вроде:
select ... 
  from ... 
  where "имя табл"."поле с датой" > (sysdate - "на сколько надо смотреть в прошлое")
либо внести в таблицу какой то key id который после каждого insert делает id++

Comment: В MS SQL есть. В других СУБД тоже часто попадается в виде `LIMIT`. И сортировка полезна, чтобы результат был детерминированным, в идеале она должна быть по набору полей с уникальными значениями.

Comment: Предполагаю, это информация связана с журналами отката и логирования, и не имеет отношения к идеям реляционных БД. Согласен, что сортировка в купе с limit видимо даст ожидаемый эффект.

Comment: В реляционных БД при наличии сортировки по уникальному ключу понятие порядка записей - ЕСТЬ. При отсутствии сортировки - нет. При неуникальности ключа сортировки - есть до уровня группы и нет внутри группы.